# Issue with pushing only one file to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, nltk

Below is my flask project structure. I have issues with nltk on heroku, so based on some documentation, I included NLTK data folder in my project and added all the files in git and pushed it to heroku. For the next time, if I just change app.py file and want to push only app.py then I did as I showed in the below commands. But every time I make change and add only one file to git, commit and push it is taking forever.

```
C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is B08D-8A75

 Directory of C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices

08/04/2016  02:18 PM    <DIR>          .
08/04/2016  02:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/05/2016  10:40 AM                18 .gitignore
08/05/2016  12:07 PM             1,546 app.py
08/03/2016  06:52 PM               369 instructions.txt
08/03/2016  06:42 PM    <DIR>          mywebservices
08/04/2016  02:30 PM    <DIR>          nltk_data
08/03/2016  06:38 PM                21 Procfile
08/04/2016  02:33 PM               135 requirements.txt
               5 File(s)          2,089 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  12,047,900,672 bytes free
```

Below are the commands used. Large number of files are getting pushed for even a minor change in app.py. Am I missing anything please let me know.

```
C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices>git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 19 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices>git add app.py

C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices>git commit -m "testing nltk"
[master 5990375] testing nltk
 Committer: mysys <mysys@mydomain.com>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your mysys and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices>

C:\Users\mysys\mywebservices>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 23025, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects:  82% (18925/22974)
```

Comment: You are not pushing a single commit, you are pushing 19 commits: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 19 commits.`

Comment: @1615903 but what's the way to update only one file, can I do a pull request from heroku to local and make changes and push again?

Answer (score 0):

Pushing to Heroku usually takes a decent amount of time, because every time you push to Heroku:

- You first upload all of your project code to Heroku. If you've made a lot of changes (which you have in this case, your logs show you're pushing 19 commits), you might be pushing a large amount of data to Heroku.
- Next, Heroku scans your project and runs their buildpack scripts.
- Heroku then attempts to install all of your project dependencies (even if nothing has changed). This might take a while depending on how many dependencies your project has.
- Heroku then builds a 'pseudo' image out of your fully built project.
- Heroku then takes this pseudo image and deploys it to however many dynos you have running.
- Heroku then removes your old dynos and replaces them with the new dynos after waiting for a set timeout.

Comment: thx for the explanation. I have nltk_data folder which is around 3GB. I uploaded this once to heroku and this will never change again. So for each time I make some changes to other files, it seems whole project is getting uploaded again. This is making my dev very slow.

Comment: Each time you push to Heroku you're pushing incremental changes to your build. So, if you make large modifications that result in large binary differences, then you'll have a large amount of data to push to Heroku. There's really nothing you can do about this except to get a faster network connection, perform less large changes, or push more frequently.